# std::atomic<int> - load and reset to 0 atomically?

Tags: c++, c++11

Having `std::atomic<int>` how can I atomically load value and reset to `0`? So If I do this operation from two threads, only one receive value, another should receive `0`.

Comment: Not at all clear. Can you put a pseudo code for what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Can you use [`exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/exchange)? Just have both threads do `int result = atomic_value.exchange(0)`.

Answer (score 13):

```
std::atomic<int> x = 1;
int y = x.exchange(0);
```